# Получаю исключение в проекте c# после установки SixLabors.ImageSharp из NuGet

Tags: c#

Ошибка такая

Ошибка  CS1705  Сборка "SixLabors.ImageSharp" с удостоверением "SixLabors.ImageSharp, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d998eea7b14cab13" использует "System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" с более высокой версией, чем у сборки "System.Runtime" с удостоверением "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", на которую делается ссылка.

Нужно установить версию runtime 6? А где?

Comment: Проект должен быть .NET 6 и выше

Comment: А можно ли повысить версию .NET проекта?

Comment: В свойствах проекта указывайте нужную. Но могут быть проблемы.

Comment: Да, проблема в том, что там максимальная версия которую можно установить это .NET 4.8, я скачал .NET 6, но все равно он там не появился

Comment: Ну, значит у вас древний проект. Пробуйте ассистента миграции, либо руками (об этом всем сказано в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/modernize-desktop/example-migration)).

Comment: Пересоздайте проект под .NET 6 и выше

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в том что я не различал .NET Framework и .NET, а потому и не
мог найти шестую версию. Все переделал, все работает, спасибо ребят)